# Does JSTL Make JSP pages running slow?

Tags: jsp, jstl

Some time, more JSP servlet developers may say that JSTL must be used in JSP instead of scriptlets.My question is not to ask whether it should be or not.But, if JSTL is used in JSP pages,does it cause to make jsp page running slow or effects to the performance,effiency as it loads some other classes together with jsp servlets?( Also does the number of times we use JSTL inside a jsp page effect,too?)
 OR
even though a little performance issue is available, can it be neglected because of JSTL's benefits/advantages over plain scriptlets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response time of a web app mainly depends on the network latency and on the IO (database requests, for example) in server-side code (and I'm ignoring the cost of rendering by the browser here, which is also non negligible, especially if images, scripts, etc. must be loaded).

The JSTL vs. scriptlet time difference is negligible, and you should favor clean code, best practices, maintainability and separation of concerns rather than trying to gain a few nanoseconds by using scriptlets. If JSTL caused performance problems, they would have been noticed, and would have been fixed already (or nobody would use it and recommend it).